# add multiple row dynamically

Tags: javascript

This is example of my code.. 
from the example, I've got two rows..
What I want to do is, I want to add the two rows dynamically..
thank you

```
<table id="datatable">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
    <b>Add</b>
</button>
function addRow(tableID) {
    alert('ttt');
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zLXmQ/)

Comment: yes can.. just give your best answer :)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486108/add-rows-to-a-table-with-jquery

Comment: @AlenGenzić : the example didnt work with me.. could you please modify my script so i can use it? tq

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

***HTML***

```
<table id="datatable">
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  /></td>
       </tr>
     </table> 

<button type="button" id="add" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
        <b>Add</b>
 </button>
```

***JS***

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function(){ 
        $('#datatable').append(' <tr> <td>Account No</td> <td>:</td> <td colspan="2"><input size="20" type="text" /></td> <td>Bill No</td> <td>:</td> <td><input type="text" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Name</td> <td>:</td> <td colspan="2"><input type="text" /></td> <td>Bill date</td> <td>:</td> <td><input type="text" /></td> </tr>');
}); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLXmQ/4/

Comment: your jsfiddle example is mine :)

Comment: obviously...I had to keep it same as you but working so that u can paste it as it is

Comment: @SyazriAris   Did u used my answer??

Comment: yes.. i try use your answer.. but its not what i want.. can u try modify my answer so it usable? thanks

Comment: A row is adding on click of add. What more may i add in it to make it useful for u?

Comment: my script already work if only add one row.. how if u have 10 row with complex row and column?

Comment: No man, your fiddle wasn't working even for 1 row. Please be clear in what are you asking. Your question is asking something else and you comment something else?

Comment: ok im sorry.. my title already ask 'add multiple row dynamically'.. so if u have an answer, pls share with me... i really appreciate it..

Comment: about 9 to 10 row.. i give u the example

`<tr>
      <td>Account No</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input size="20" type="text"  /></td>
      <td>Bill No</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text"  /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text"  /></td>
      <td>Bill date</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text"  /></td>
     </tr>`

Comment: You mean add these all rows on click of add?

Comment: ok..so i am editing my nswer and giving you a fiddle also to make chages as you want.  Check and tell if it helps.:)

Comment: last question.. could u add button to remove each row .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just browsing through and would like to point out that your table id- is datatable and your parameter is dataTable. hopefully thats pertinent

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do this :

```
function addRow(tableId)
{
  $('#' + tableId + ' tr:last').after('<tr><td>Enter You New Row Data Here..</td></tr>');
}
```

for more information check this : [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)